# sorting numbers into ascending order on a line

Tags: python, python-2.7

So i have the following output in file (thousands of lines)
input.txt

```
2956:1 1076:1 4118:1 1378:1 2561:1 
1039:1 1662:1
1948:1 894:1 1797:1 1662:1
```

the problem is i need to have each line sorted in ascending number

Desired output:
output.txt

```
1076:1 1378:1 2561:1 2956:1 4118:1
1039:1 1662:1
894:1 1662:1 1797:1 1948:1
```

This is becoming a real challenge to get it right, im looking for a python function to do this for me. The lines have to stay in order they are in, but each line must be sorted in ascending number (just like the output).

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
with open('input.txt') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()  #splits the line on whitespaces and returns a list
        #sort the list based on the integer value of the item on the left side of the `:`
        line.sort(key = lambda x: int(x.split(':')[0]))
        out.write(" ".join(line) + '\n')
```

**output:**

```
1076:1 1378:1 2561:1 2956:1 4118:1
1039:1 1662:1
894:1 1662:1 1797:1 1948:1
```

Comment: Why do Python answers get so much love ;-)

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary ...........1 question, how i make sure it removes doubles per line? not doubles from file, just not allowed to have doubles in line....svm software dont like it :P

Comment: @RHK-S8 what do you mean by doubles?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about python, but in general, I'd take each line as a "record" then "explode" the line into an array separated by a space (or regex a group of spaces or tab, or whatever is the separator), then a simple array sort, then "implode" back to a string.

My "quotes" are equivalent to PHP functions.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is like this:

```
def sort_input(input_file):
  for line in input_file:
    nums = line.strip().split()
    nums.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split(':')[0]))
    print ' '.join(nums)
```